# Specified deployed URL's content is not getting displayed in the dialog triggered through in-meeting notification payload

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

This is continuation of the issue raised in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1350208/no-content-getting-displayed-within-the-teams-meet as I am afraid that thread might not be getting monitored anymore.

1)This is the repository that is being used to generate the meeting dialog- https://github.com/messibarbie/Notification-App

2)This is the React app's repository of which we have tried taking the URL from to render its content in the meeting dialog- https://github.com/messibarbie/Dialog-React-SPA . We have attempted running this app locally and using one of its route URLs http://localhost:3000/#/privacy to render in the meeting dialog which did not generate any content in the dialog.

3)We have also tried taking the URL of a Teams tab app created using Teams toolkit for visual studio code and rendering it in the dialog. When we are running this Tab app locally and use its **localhost URL**, its **content DOES get successfully generated** in the meeting dialog. **However**, when I **deploy** this tab app using teams toolkit for visual studio code and try using its **Deployed** URL to generate its content in the meeting dialog, **no content gets generated** in the meeting dialog for it which is interesting since its localhost version had worked. I can confirm that I did not face any issue with the deployed URL when I called it in the browser. The content got rendered without any issue unlike what happens inside the dialog. Here is another deployed URL which does not have any issue in the browser but no content gets displayed for it in the dialog- https://tab-personal.azurewebsites.net/privacy .
Below is a screenshot of how the dialog looks like when I use the deployed URL.

[image]

I have provided link to my repository above which can be used to replicate the issues that I have mentioned here. Can you please confirm:
1)Why does the url of teams tab app created using teams toolkit for vs code gets rendered without any issue in the meeting dialog when the app is being run locally and the URL is a localhost URL but deployed URL of the same tab app does not get rendered in the meeting dialog even though I face no issue to render its contents in the browser?

2)Why does the URL of a react app created using create-react-app in command prompt does not get rendered in the meeting even when we are running the app locally unlike the Teams tab app when that was run locally?

I would need the URL content to get rendered in the meeting dialog but there seems to be issues around it at the moment.